# How to determine if tooltip is cut off from the top of a page

Tags: javascript, math, positioning

I have a tooltip that opens via javascript on mouseover. From the following values how can I determine if this tooltip is cut off from the top edge of the screen (in this case it is) :

```
top margin: 72.5 inner height: 607 offsettop: 75 offsetheight: 26
```

and here are values from a tooltip below it that is not cut off, and fits perfectly in the window: 
`top margin: 53.5 inner height: 607 offsettop: 209 offsetheight: 222`

I want to be able to detect if the tooptip is cut off and then apply changes to the margin to push it down to fit in the screen.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? I tried `if (e.offsetTop+e.offsetHeight>self.innerheight)` bu no avail

Answer (score 1):

```
if (left + width > viewportWidth || top + height > viewportHeight) {
   // Off the viewport
}
```

Comment: I tried `if (e.offsetTop+e.offsetHeight>self.innerheight) ` but this does not trigger when the element is cut off at the top?